# TLS Verification does NOT fail although the CA root is NOT set in IE

Tags: tls, certificates

As far as I know: when we make an ssl connection to a site we receive the site certificate, the browser check if the site certificate is in its list of root and trusted certification.

So if the CA is NOT in the browser trusted roots the connection should fail!

I made a connection to [saba.bankmelli-iran.com](https://saba.bankmelli-iran.com), the site is verified by **KEYNECTIS**,

1. I can find this CA as a valid root in **firefox** so I expect **firefox** connect to this site without any problem, and it does ! ( I find the certificates at preferences#advanced#view-certificates#Authorities menu)
2. I can not find the **KEYNECTIS** in IE CA valid roots, I expect that IE does not trust this, but it goes and I get now Certification Warning. (I find the roots at internet_options#content#certificates#trusted_root_certification_authorities menu)

Why does IE trust this CA?

Here is a screenshot of IE Key store

[image]

Comment: what IE version? what's the cert warning? can you confirm the certificate path in IE?

Comment: KEYNECTIS is not the root for me. The root is CertPlus. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @schroeder yes this is CertPlus

Comment: Dear @JohnWu I see `CLASS 2 KEYNECTIS CA` is signed by `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA`. Well, Let me ask this way, the `saba.bankmelli-iran.com` CA say that My root signer is `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA`, Is it enough for a CA to be valid ... I think NO ! , how the browser knows that the `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA` is a valid root ?! I guess the only way is that The `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA`  must be stored in windows key store.... please correct me if my assumption is wrong!

Comment: I think that you do not understand CAs

Comment: It would have helped if you included what the error was, like I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ran all of us into a wild chase.

Your screenshot shows `Class 2 Primary CA` in your Trusted Roots. This is the root CA for the site you linked.

KEYNECTIS is ***not*** the root of the site you linked, but is a CA signed by Class 2 Primary CA in your trusted root.

Nothing is wrong. Everything is working as intended.

http://certificate.fyicenter.com/340_Root_CA_Class_2_Primary_CA_Certplus_FR.html

Comment: The link finally helped me. I am very new in this topic, thanks for helping. For others which have same misunderstanding : when you open windows keystore tool, there are four columns for each certificate, the last one is `Friendly Name` which is not always same as `Issued To`. In my case I was looking for `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA` (exact string) in the `Issued To`  column, while I should looked at `Friendly Name` column.  Thank you all for being patient :)

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Stephan's answer:

CLASS 2 KEYNECTIS CA is signed by CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA.

CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA is in the root certificate store on Windows and FireFox.

Comment: Dear @paj28 I could not find the `CertPlus Class 2 Primay CA` in the key store and this is my problem. I have update my question and add a screen shoot of my key store `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`. I used this menu internet_options#content#certificates#trusted_root_certification_authorities

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi - Did you remove it? It's there by default (at least, it's there on my machine and I never manually installed it)

Comment: Now you get my point :) Well I have not removed it at all !! At least if I have removed it I should get CA validation warning/error. But I am connection with no error. I am using IE 11 on Windows 10

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi - Perhaps it is still there but not displaying for some reason. Is the CertPlus certificate in FireFox? Other possibility is you have some upstream SSL breaking proxy, but this would be visible in the certificate path of saba.bankmelli-iran.com. Perhaps include screenshots of those so people can see more clearly

Comment: @paj28 see my answer - everything is working as intended